# Regex that only matches when no duplicate lines are found

Tags: regex, multiline

I have a multiline string like this:

```
SA21 abcdef
BKxyz
SA21 abcdef
```

I need a regex that only matches if the line `^SA21 abcdef$` is present once. So it should not match for the first example but it should match for this one:

```
BK udsia
SA21 abcdef
BKxyz
```

I tried to capture the line and make sure it matches only when the same line is not found later: `/(^SA21 abcdef$)(?!\1)/m` [regex101](https://www.regex101.com/r/nS8sD8/1) but that does not work as it will probably always match the last line...

Comment: Try [`\A(?:(?!^SA21 abcdef$).)*(^SA21 abcdef$)(?:(?!^SA21 abcdef$).)*\z`](https://www.regex101.com/r/vN4tQ9/1) (just want to know if that is the right direction).

Comment: Why not just match it, and then check how many matches there were and make the `if` about that?

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I can't easily use code as we use the regex from a dsl

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That looks quite good... Let me test it

Comment: @Chris Okay - with questions like this, my gut feeling is always that regex might not be the right tool for the job, so I ask that first ;)

Comment: @FlorianPeschka I know, I'd also prefer to just use code but that would require us to extend the dsl just for this single use case...

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Looks good... Can we simplify the expression a bit so we don't have to repeat the string?

Comment: Why do you ask to not repeat the string? :) I think you should ask how to make it faster, more efficient and robust.

Comment: Try [`/\A(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*\n*^(SA21 abcdef)$(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*\z/m`](https://www.regex101.com/r/vN4tQ9/4). Note that DOTALL option should be removed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex you want should only match a *line* if the line is not present before or after the single occurrence of the line. This is achieved with a tempered greedy token:

```
/\A(?:(?!^SA21 abcdef$).)*(^SA21 abcdef$)(?:(?!^SA21 abcdef$).)*\z/ms
```

See the [regex demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vN4tQ9/1)

The `(?:(?!^SA21 abcdef$).)*` is the token matching any text but the beginning of the `SA21 abcdef` line. The `/s` modifier is required so that a `.` could match a newline.

However, the construct is resource consuming, and it is a good idea to unroll it:

```
/\A(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*\n*^(SA21 abcdef)$(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*\z/m
```

See [another demo](https://www.regex101.com/r/vN4tQ9/4)

Note that `\A` and `\z` are unambiguous start/end *string* anchors, the `/m` modifier does not affect them.

**Pattern explanation**:

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*` - zero or more sequences of:

  - `\n+` - 1 or more newlines ...
  - `(?!SA21 abcdef$)` - not followed with `SA21 abcdef` that is the whole line
  - `.*` - zero or more chars other than a newline
- `\n*` - zero or more newlines
- `^` - start of a line
- `(SA21 abcdef)` - the line that must be single
- `$` - end of line
- `(?:\n+(?!SA21 abcdef$).*)*` - see above
- `\z` - end of string.